# Bullet Physics, Linking Error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Bullet Physics, on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012. I have compiled the libraries, and the demos are working fine, but when I try to create my own solution, I am getting linking errors. I have minimised the amount of code to

```
#include "btBulletDynamicsCommon.h"
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    btBoxShape* box = new btBoxShape(btVector3(1, 1, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Which when I link, using Visual Studio gives me the following Errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloBulletApp, Configuration: Release Win32 ------  
1>  main.cpp  
1>  main.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG;   add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
1>BulletCollision.lib(btCollisionShape.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for   'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
1>BulletCollision.lib(btConvexShape.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for   'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
1>BulletCollision.lib(btPolyhedralConvexShape.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for   'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
1>BulletCollision.lib(btConvexPolyhedron.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for   'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
1>LinearMath.lib(btConvexHullComputer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
1>LinearMath.lib(btGeometryUtil.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>c:\path\to\HelloBulletApp\HelloBulletApp\Release\HelloBulletApp.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 6 mismatches detected
```

The same errors are appearing when I build in Debug or Release Mode.
I've tried:
- rebuilding bullet 2.81,
- redownloading 2.81,
- creating a blank project and adding the libraries,
- creating a blank project and adding the Projects as suggested at  http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Creating_a_project_from_scratch,
but to no avail.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like BulletCollision.lib was compiled to link with the DLL version of the C runtime library (/MD), but you're compiling to link with the statically linked runtime library (/MT).  Change your compiler options to link with the DLL runtime library.

Comment: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library